# The path of my image is being changed in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

**Here is the code I use to get the favorite products of the user**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Pagination, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProductToWishlist } from "../../RTK/Slices/wishlistSlice";
import CardProductCountainer from "../products/CardProductCountainer";
import ProductCard from "../products/ProductCard";

const UserFavoriteProduct = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const get = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      await dispatch(getProductToWishlist());
      setLoading(false);
    };
    get();
  }, []);

  const res = useSelector((state) => state.wishlistSlice.allWishList);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading === false) {
      if (res) {
        setItems(
          res.data.map((item) => {
            const { id, imageCover, images } = item;
            return {
              ...item,
              images: {
                [id]: {
                  cover: imageCover,
                  others: images,
                },
              },
            };
          })
        );
      }
    }
  }, [loading]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="admin-content-text pb-4">قائمة المفضلة</div>
      <Row className="justify-content-start">
        {items.length <= 0 ? (
          <h6>لا يوجد منتجات مفضله حاليا</h6>
        ) : (
          <CardProductCountainer products={items} title="" btntitle="" />
        )}
      </Row>
      <Pagination />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserFavoriteProduct;
```

**The path of img is supposed to look like this:**

```
"imageCover": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/products-8bad93c1-19eb-4011-9dc6-dc3f704ed83c-1685630224582-cover.jpeg",
"images": [
  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/products-34218803-805d-4eb4-98c8-ada648f98fa8-1685630224597-1.jpeg"
],
```

**But instead it looks like this:**

"imageCover": "products-33d97001-a069-492a-bd36-de7d102a92d0-1683282946006-cover.jpeg",
"images": [
"products-fe7577fa-2c26-42cb-a46b-9666169c432a-1683282946231-2.jpeg",
"products-4f4c53e1-9bc4-4433-bec7-61d37f18e3f7-1683282946230-1.jpeg"
],

**Without http://127.0.0.1:8000,Wwhat can I do to fix this?**

**Here is the CardProductCountainer component:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProductToWishlist } from "../../RTK/Slices/wishlistSlice";
import SubTitle from "../utilitys/SubTitle";
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard";

const CardProductCountainer = ({ title, btntitle, pathText, products }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [favProd, setFavProd] = useState([]);
  
  const res = useSelector((state) => state.wishlistSlice.allWishList);

  useEffect(() => {
    const get = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      await dispatch(getProductToWishlist());
      setLoading(false);
    };
    get();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading === false) {
      if (res.data.length >= 1) {
        console.log(res);
        setFavProd(res.data.map((item) => item._id));
      } else setFavProd([]);
    }
  }, [loading]);

  return (
    <Container>
      {products ? (
        <SubTitle title={title} btntitle={btntitle} pathText={pathText} />
      ) : null}
      <Row className="my-2 d-flex justify-content-between">
        {products
          ? products.map((item, index) => (
              <ProductCard favProd={favProd} key={index} item={item} />
            ))
          : null}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CardProductCountainer;
```

**And here is the ProductCard component:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Card, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import prod1 from "../../images/prod1.png";
import favoff from "../../images/fav-off.png";
import favon from "../../images/fav-on.png";
import rate from "../../images/rate.png";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  addProductToWishlist,
  removeProductToWishlist,
} from "../../RTK/Slices/wishlistSlice";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import notify from "../../customHook/useNotification";

const ProductCard = ({ item, favProd }) => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [favImg, setFavImg] = useState(favoff);
  let Fav = favProd.some((fitem) => fitem === item._id);
  const [loadingAdd, setLoadingAdd] = useState(true);
  const [loadingRemove, setLoadingRemove] = useState(true);
  const [isFav, setIsFav] = useState(Fav);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsFav(favProd.some((fitem) => fitem === item._id));
  }, [favProd]);

  const handelFav = () => {
    if (isFav) {
      removeToWishListData();
    } else {
      addToWishListData();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFav === true) {
      setFavImg(favon);
    } else {
      setFavImg(favoff);
    }
  }, [isFav]);

  const resAdd = useSelector((state) => state.wishlistSlice.addWishlist);
  const resRemove = useSelector((state) => state.wishlistSlice.removeWishlist);

  const addToWishListData = async () => {
    setIsFav(true);
    setFavImg(favon);
    setLoadingAdd(true);
    await dispatch(
      addProductToWishlist({
        productId: item._id,
      })
    );
    setLoadingAdd(false);
  };

  const removeToWishListData = async () => {
    setIsFav(false);
    setFavImg(favoff);
    setLoadingRemove(true);
    await dispatch(removeProductToWishlist(item._id));
    setLoadingRemove(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingAdd === false) {
      if (resAdd && resAdd.status === 200) {
        notify("تمت اضافة المنتج للمفضلة بنجاح", "success");
      } else if (resAdd && resAdd.status === 401) {
        notify("انت غير مسجل", "error");
      }
    }
  }, [loadingAdd]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingRemove === false) {
      if (resRemove && resRemove.status === "success") {
        notify("تمت حذف المنتج من المفضلة بنجاح", "warn");
      } else if (resAdd && resAdd.status === 401) {
        notify("انت غير مسجل", "error");
      }
    }
  }, [loadingRemove]);
  return (
    <Col xs="6" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" className="d-flex">
      <Card
        className="my-2"
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "345px",
          borderRadius: "8px",
          border: "none",
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          boxShadow: "0 2px 2px 0 rgba(151,151,151,0.5)",
        }}
      >
        <Link to={`/products/${item._id}`} state={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <Card.Img
            style={{ height: "228px", width: "100%" }}
            src={item.imageCover}
          />
        </Link>

        <div className="d-flex justify-content-end mx-2">
          <img
            src={favImg}
            onClick={handelFav}
            alt=""
            className="text-center"
            style={{
              height: "24px",
              width: "26px",
              cursor: "pointer",
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>
            <div className="card-title">{item.title}</div>
          </Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between ">
              <div className="d-flex">
                <img
                  className=""
                  src={rate}
                  alt=""
                  height="16px"
                  width="16px"
                />
                <div className="card-rate mx-2">{item.ratingsAverage || 0}</div>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex">
                <div className="card-price">{item.price}</div>
                <div className="card-currency mx-1">جنيه</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <ToastContainer />
    </Col>
  );
};


export default ProductCard;
```

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi, there 
> First of all welcome to stack overflow, if you want to get good
> response here make sure to make your question good. Keep it detailed
> as above but avoid typos and check for grammatical errors.

Anyways here is how you can solve the above problem. for further questions comment on the answer. And follow the steps to solve the problem.

**1. Declear a `constant` holding your site `url`.**

*Example:*

```
const URL = "127.0.0.1:8000";
```

**2. Append the `URL` before using the image source.**

*Example:*

```
<Card.Img
 style={{ height: "228px", width: "100%" }}
 src={ URL + item.imageCover }
 />
```

I hope this helps. If so give it a upvote. And make sure to Improve your question look through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you can ask better questions.

Thank you ☺️

PS. **Edit**
Those who are unsure about the above problem the problem is now solved and was caused by the data that was coming out of the `server`. Anyways the solution in this answer also works equally as well.

Comment: thnx for replying but could you explain more details I did not understand you will,what should I change or add to my code

Comment: As far as I understood your problem, you said you wanted your `url` to be in the format `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/product-cover.jpeg` but instead you got `products/products-...-1-cover.jpeg`
without the ip part ? so, I suggested you to add it manually by creating a new url where you need to use the image url, for example if you want to render that image tag then you can just append the Url that was created as constant before the url without the ip part. And the constant conains the suitable ip. is it clear? if not ib me in any socials.

Comment: how could i ib you  
Saroj Regmi ? give me any link to contact please

Comment: Go to my profile and choose any socials of your choice. I believe I have added all of the socials that I use.

Comment: If you were unable to find it then, I go by sarojregmi200 in every platform,twitter, linkedin, github, instagram, reddit, youtube, hashnode.

Comment: ok, I dm you on Instagram

Comment: thx for contacting me you are very helpful man who needs to help others  3 houses with to solve  it soo thnx man...  Saroj Regmi

Comment: You are welcome, It was a refreshment looking at the web after a long time.